# ASP.NET MVC 5 Dual Authentication Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

I have a requirement for a new MVC5 web app am working on. 
I need to use active directory based authentication for the back-end,and  SQL server based authentication for regular users.
in our company's local applications I use forms authentication and I integrate it with active directory using custom authorize attribute, but now i have to add SQL server authentication and make them work at the same time.

is there anyone had to solve a similar problem, and if so how did you go about it ?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. You're already using forms authentication, which is good. And you're handling your own AD authentication in the background.... can you not handle SQL authentication the same way you're handling the AD authentication?

Comment: sorry for late reply but it was holiday season..

Comment: the problem is in -- Membership.ValidateUser() -- because it uses the membership provider set in web.config which is -- ADMembershipProvider --.
so my question is how can i specify which type of authentication to use depending on the login page? and how to handle setting cookies for back-end and front end? 
and thanks for your reply.

Comment: @gabriel-luci  ss